# What percentage of economists recommend basic welfare like food stamps and temporary assistance for needy families?

Tags: welfare-economics, social-welfare

Is it similar to minimum wage in that opinion is approximately split down party lines, seen in this 2006 survey: https://people.uwec.edu/jamelsem/fte/fte/efl/teacher_stuff/articles/economists_agree.pdf?

Why or why not?

Comment: Economists study things like "What will happen if we introduce food stamps?", not "Should we introduce food stamps?". "Should" depends on our goals and values. Your question is basically about percentage of economists that have pro-basic welfare values

Comment: "split down party lines" What country are you talking about?

Comment: That study is for the USA, so that is what I was referring to.

Comment: Is anything in the USA *not* split down party lines?

Comment: @user253751 https://gregmankiw.blogspot.com/2009/02/news-flash-economists-agree.html